# How to retrieve information in address book that reads from console

Tags: java

In my class we have make address book. The problem I need help with is when a user chooses to look up a contacts info it needs to be by last name, once last name entered all of contact's info is displayed.If given last name is not in list message displays that. And if there is more than 1 person w/given last name that all names are displayed. How exactly do I go about doing this?

```
          --------This is ContactList--------

       /**
      * One object of this class is
      * responsible for everyone's contact
      */
     import java.util.ArrayList;//A.M.
     import java.util.Collections;//A.M.

   public class ContactList  {//A.M.
public ArrayList<Contact> contacts;//A.M.
// creates arraylist
ContactList(){//A.M.
    contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();//A.M.

}
// Add contact to array list
public void add(Contact contact){//A.M.
    contacts.add(contact);//A.M.

}

// calls and returns toString from class Contact
public String toString(){//A.M.
    String contactInfo = "";//A.M.
    for (Contact contact : contacts){//A.M.
        contactInfo += contact.toString() + "\n";//A.M.
    }
    return contactInfo;//A.M.
}
```

}

```
           ---------This is class Contact------------


/**
* One object of this class is 
 * responsible for one person's contact
 **/
import java.util.Scanner;//A.M.

 public class Contact   {//A.M.
private String firstName, lastName, address, city, state, zip, email,
        phoneNumber, notes;//A.M.
        Scanner scanner;//A.M.



// puts contact's information in the desired order
public String  toString() {//A.M.
    return firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + address + "\n" + city + ", "
            + state + " " + zip + "\n" + email + "\n" + phoneNumber + "\n"
                + notes + "\n";//A.M.


}
/** Reads the contact information
 * takes user input and updates private members of class
 * @return boolean to read if method returns true if contact info was read successfully,
 * returns false otherwise
 */

public boolean read() {//A.M.A.J.
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);//A.M.
    System.out.print("First Name : ");//A.M.
    firstName = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("Last Name : ");//A.M.
    lastName = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.

    if (lastName.equals("") ) {//A.J.
         return false;
     }

    System.out.print("Address : ");//A.M.
    address = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("City : ");//A.M.
    city = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("State : ");//A.M.
    state = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("Zip : ");//A.M.
    zip = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("Email Address : ");//A.M.
    email = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("Phone Number : ");//A.M.
    phoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
    System.out.print("Notes about the contact : ");//A.M.
    notes = scanner.nextLine();//A.M.
           return true;
}
```

}

```
                ---------This is Class TestContact----------------

/**
* One object of this class is 
* responsible for everyone's contact
 */
import java.util.Scanner;//A.M.

public class TestContact { // A.M.
public static void main(String args[]) {// A.M.
    Contact contact;// A.M.
    contact = new Contact();// A.M.
    ContactList contactList;// A.M.
    contactList = new ContactList();// A.M.
    Scanner scanner;// A.M.
    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);// A.M.
    int option = 1;// A.M.
    // calls scanner in class Contact
    boolean readSuccessful; // A.J.

    // While allows the switch statement to start over after an option is
    // selected
    while (option != 4) {// A.M.
        // Menu for the contact program
        System.out.println("Contact List");
        System.out.println("Add a new contact : 1");
        System.out
                .println("Search for an existing contact by last name : 2");
        System.out.println("Print your entire contact list : 3");
        System.out.println("Quit program : 4");

        // replaces
        option = scanner.nextInt();// A.M.
        switch (option) {// A.M.
        case 1:
            contact = new Contact();// A.M.
            readSuccessful = contact.read();// A.J.
            if (readSuccessful == false) {// A.J.
                System.out.println("Need to enter Last Name");// A.J.
            } else {
                contactList.add(contact);// A.M.
                System.out.println("Contact added to list \n");// A.M.
            }
            // Prints toString from array in class ContactList
            System.out.println(contactList.toString());// A.M.
            break;

        case 2:

            break;

        case 3:
            // Prints toString from array in class ContactList
            System.out.println(contactList.toString());// A.M.

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Program has been closed.");// A.M.
            break;

        default:
            // if wrong input is used it will give a warning
            System.out.println("Not a valid option.\n");// A.M.
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: How do I retrieve a persons contact info by last name?